# Formatar numero com javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tenho o seguinte valor: `7500`
Como faço para ter esse valor como resultado final: `75.00`, gostaria de usar somente javascript puro.

Outros exemplos:

```
76000 > 760.00
1600 > 16.00
```

Tentei usar toFixed mas não deu certo

```js
var number = 76900
var value = parseFloat(Math.round(number * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)
console.log(value)//Esperava 769.00 como resultado
```

Comment: Para confirmar, você dividiu por 100 antes de utilizar o `toFixed`? https://repl.it/@acwoss/AjarAshamedInstitute

Comment: coloquei um exemplo de como fiz @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Por quê multiplicou por 100 também?

Comment: Tira o `* 100`, aliais nem o `Math.round` faz sentido ali :/ ao menos não a primeira vista. O `.toFixed(2)` já resolve quase "tudo".

Comment: resolvido, tirei o * 100

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, usei `parseFloat(Math.round(number / 100)).toFixed(2)`